# Arithmetic right-shift a size_t value

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

The `size_t` type is an unsigned type. As such, right-shifting a value of type `size_t` will shift logically. Given that the width of `size_t` is implementation dependent, is there any way to right-shift a `size_t` value arithmetically?

If my goal is to create a bitmask from a `size_t` value containing a `1` or a `0`, is there another way to do it? For integers with known widths, the easiest way I know to make a bitmask is to left-shift the width of the integer - 1, then arithmetically right-shift all the way back.

This works on my 64-bit system:

```
const size_t width = (sizeof(size_t) << 3)) - 1;
size_t value = {boolean value};
value = ((int64_t) (value << width)) >> width;
```

But of course it's specific to my system and systems like it. What can I use instead?

Comment: If I understand correctly, what you want is effectively `size_t mask = original ? -1 : 0;`, if by "creating a mask from a value containing a 1 or a 0" you mean sign extension from 1 bit to however many bits `size_t` has.

Comment: Yeah, pretty much. Part of me wanted to do it without a ternary operator. But I'm also still curious if there's a good way to do an arithmetic right-shift.

Comment: The downvote is not mine this time.

Comment: I wish I understood the two downvotes. If it's about the structure of the question, I'm happy to split it in two (one for the bitmask and one for the actual right-shift in general).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original code …

```
const size_t width = (sizeof(size_t) << 3)) - 1;
size_t inpvalue = {zero or one};
size_t outvalue = ((int64_t) (value << width)) >> width;
```

… can be simplified in this way:

```
size_t inpvalue = {zero or one};
size_t outvalue = -inpvalue;
```

Comment: Oh yeah, negation does that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
#define UNSIGNED_SRA(x,n) ((x)<=(0?(x):-1)/2 ? (x)>>(n) : ~(~(x)>>(n)))
```

The expression `(0?(x):-1)/2` evaluates to the maximum value for the type of `x` that has the high bit clear; if you know a specific type, like `size_t`, you can just use `SIZE_MAX/2`.

Any good optimizing compiler for a machine that has an arithmetic right shift opcode should recognize that the two branches are identical for the cases they handle, and optimize out the branch entirely, producing a single branch-free operation.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to right-shift a size_t value arithmetically?

Yes, there is. In fact, given a value `v` of an unsigned type, I believe you can perform an arithmetic right shift as follows (example for `size_t`):

```
v = (v >> 1U) | (v & ~(~(size_t) 0 >> 1U));
```

Basically, it performs a logical right shift and then sets the most significant bit to 1 if the most significant bit before shifting is a 1.

Here's a small toy program to run a few tests:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_binary(size_t v) {
    size_t mask = ~(~(size_t) 0 >> 1U);
    while (mask) {
        putchar('0'+!!(v&mask));
        mask >>= 1U;
    }
    putchar('\n');
}

int main() {
    size_t v;

    // Some random number
    v = 5583705;
    print_binary(v);
    v = (v >> 1U) | (v & ~(~(size_t) 0 >> 1U));
    print_binary(v);

    v = ~(~(size_t) 0 >> 1U);
    print_binary(v);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        v = (v >> 1U) | (v & ~(~(size_t) 0 >> 1U));
        print_binary(v);
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

On my machine, this prints:

```
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000010101010011001101011001
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000001010101001100110101100
1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
1100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
1110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
1111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
1111100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
1111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
1111111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
1111111100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
1111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
1111111111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
1111111111100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Seems to work fine.

For your specific problem, I believe dlask's answer is the best approach here, but I decided to post this answer because you showed interest in knowing how (and if) it is possible to do arithmetic right shifts on unsigned types.

Comment: Thanks! I was rather curious about the general case (and it seemed like a better question that way).